# Align labels to pyramid barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I don't succeed to align the numbers with each of the bars in my ggplot graph. Another problem is I would like to remove the message "fill" above the legend but I don't understand how it appeared. Thanks for your help.

```r
graph <- ggplot(df, aes(x=labs)) +
  geom_bar(data=df[df$isEmotion=="emotion",], aes(y=RTU, fill = "Emotion"), stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(data=df[df$isEmotion=="no emotion",], aes(y=-RTU, fill = "No Emotion"), stat="identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="white", lwd=1) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15)) +
  coord_flip(ylim=lim) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=breaks, labels=labels) +
  labs(y="RTU", x="Collaborative acts") +
  ggtitle("               Interested") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(RTU), y=RTU))
```

### Data:

#### Variables:

```
lim = c(-1.6,1.6)
breaks = seq(-1.6,1.6,0.4)
labels = c(1.6,1.2,0.8,0.4,0,0.4,0.8,1.2,1.6)
```

Data table via `dput`:

```
structure(list(labs = structure(c(29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 
23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 
10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 
25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Show Hostility", 
"Elicit Recall", "Check Comprehension", "Refuse", "Show Solidarity", 
"Give Explanation", "Elicit Proposition", "Incorporate", "Use Social Convention", 
"Elicit Partner Information", "Outside Activity", "Give Opinion Against", 
"Coordinate Teamwork", "Check Reception", "Elicit Task Information", 
"Show Active Listening", "Elicit Opinion", "Give Recall", "Give Task Information", 
"Give Self Information", "Relax Atmosphere", "Manage Task", "Give Proposition", 
"Tool Discourse", "Show Reflection", "Accept", "Agree", "Other", 
"Give Opinion For"), class = "factor"), RTU = c(1.33679949277407, 
1.113629906839, 0.998523521750659, 0.774259935575577, 0.659963240986954, 
0.60839106356628, 0.6065649859483, 0.539489093267195, 0.480274995783261, 
0.423104935724923, 0.408927591199088, 0.274223979504919, 0.270110544387821, 
0.258935589229039, 0.218353068762815, 0.193643374161986, 0.177004182065326, 
0.102980320541176, 0.0980838299538663, 0.0969015258673401, 0.0734178878735949, 
0.0649985993746002, 0.054594994045725, 0.0404505716411595, 0.0345846135809401, 
0.0344802024462216, 0.0311026889658307, 0.0245605273402327, 0.00164473684210526, 
0.798245614035088, 0.631578947368421, 0.87719298245614, 1.21052631578947, 
0.657894736842105, 0.526315789473684, 0.56140350877193, 0.508771929824561, 
0.543859649122807, 0.473684210526316, 0.587719298245614, 0.236842105263158, 
0.254385964912281, 0.333333333333333, 0.280701754385965, 0.368421052631579, 
0.333333333333333, 0.175438596491228, 0.0175438596491228, 0.0701754385964912, 
0.184210526315789, 0.0175438596491228, 0.114035087719298, 0.0789473684210526, 
0, 0, 0.105263157894737, 0.0526315789473684, 0), isEmotion = c("no emotion", 
"no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", 
"no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", 
"no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", 
"no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", 
"no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", 
"no emotion", "no emotion", "no emotion", "emotion", "emotion", 
"emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", 
"emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", 
"emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", 
"emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", "emotion", 
"emotion", "emotion", "emotion")), row.names = c(NA, -58L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: This question is not reproducible, so we cannot test your code.

Comment: Two thoughts: (1) generate another `RTU` value that is negated when `"No Emotion"`; or (2) call `geom_text` twice, just like you did for `geom_bar`, negating the text.

Comment: BTW: I have found it useful to use `data = ~subset(., isEmotion=="emotion")` in lieu of repeating the whole frame, in cases where data is modified in-pipe or other complex things; the tilde-function (as ggplot allows) replaces the `.` with the data *as it is given to the function*, allowing some relatively arbitrary filtering or transforming in-place. It can easily be abused, but I have seen occasional issues reusing `df$` in here like this. (ymmv)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I actually suggest you don't use labels. Instead just make the X-axis tick marks more prominent via ` + theme(axis.text.x= element_text(size= 12, face= "bold"))`.... labeling the values of a bar chart is redundant / spurious data-ink.

Comment: If you would like an answer, we'll need a dataset to work with. Please provide via `dput`

Comment: @AlexW I added the data via dput. Thanks for that, I didn't know it.

Comment: @AlexW I added them also. It should work now =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the legend title, you can use the function `labs(fill = "")`. For aligning your labels for your pyramid, like you did for geom_bar, you need to pass two lines of `geom_text`, one for the label of the group `emotion` (and y = RTU) and one for the label of the group `no emotion` (with y = -RTU). You can adjust `hjust` in each of them to make it pretty on your plot.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = labs)) +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(., isEmotion=="emotion"), aes( y = RTU, fill = "Emotion"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = ~subset(., isEmotion=="no emotion"), aes(y = -RTU, fill = "No Emotion"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="white", lwd=1) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15)) +
  coord_flip(ylim=lim) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=breaks, labels=labels) +
  labs(y="RTU", x="Collaborative acts") +
  ggtitle("               Interested") +
  geom_text(data = ~subset(., isEmotion=="emotion"), aes(label = round(RTU, digits = 2), y = RTU), hjust = -0.75) +
  geom_text(data = ~subset(., isEmotion=="no emotion"), aes(label = round(RTU, digits = 2), y = -RTU), hjust = 1.5)+
  labs(fill = "")
```

[image]

Hope it answers your question !

Comment: Thanks very much @dc37. It is exactly what I wanted!